# How to make the website not show up on google search results or any other search engine?

Tags: magento2

I do not want Google or other search engines to crawl my website, I do not want any of the products to show in google search results. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site use this meta tag
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

To prevent only Google web crawlers from indexing a page use this meta tag `<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">`

***How to add meta tags in Magento***

In order to add  tags to your layout’s  element, you need to create a theme extending file which is similar to this: app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml.

You can use the following as an examples to include in your layout themes:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
    <!-- This will create a tag like '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">' -->
    <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <!-- This will create a tag like '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>'' -->
    <meta name="og:type" content="article"/>
    <!-- This will create a tag like '<meta charset="UTF-8">' -->
    <meta name="charset" content="UTF-8"/>
    <!-- This will create a tag like '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="content-type-value"/>' -->
    <meta name="content_type" content="content-type-value"/>
    <!-- This tag will not render (see \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer for details) -->
    <meta name="media_type" content="any-value"/>
    <!-- This will create a tag like '<meta name="my_custom_type" content="my_custom_value"/>' -->
    <meta name="my_custom_type" content="my_custom_value"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

Reference : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-meta-tags-header-magento-2.html

**OR**

Create a `robots.txt` file and upload it in your root directory.
Add the following content

`User-agent: * Disallow: /`

It will block all web crawlers from all content.

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/search-engine-robots.html
I added earlier after reading Magento docs but when I search for a product name its in its page still showing on the google search filter

Comment: Wait a few days. Google will not crawl or list any site instantly nor it will remove from crawled list instantly

Comment: thank you for answering my question even though it doesn't really help me much but i will give you 1 vote